# Drop duplicates dataframe based on other columns

Tags: dataframe, filter

I have the following dataframe df:

```
A     B     procedure
aa  pass    2
aa  pass    1
aa  fail    1
b   pass    2
b   pass    1
```

and I want the following table df1

```
A     B     procedure
aa  pass    2
aa  pass    1
b   pass    2
b   pass    1
```

Basically if for a given procedure, if it is run again and this time it is a pass i want to keep the pass and remove the fail. I'm not sure how to drop a row based on multiple conditions

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the desired result, you could simply select only `pass` values for column `B`

```
df.select("*").where("B = 'pass'")
```